# HTML5 Video on Android Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, html5-video

I'm trying to show a video on Android Emulator using HTML5

I got the video working on chorme, safari, IE & Firefox

but it's not working on the emulator

here's the code for it

```
<video id="video" onclick="this.play();" width="320" height="240" controls="controls"> 
    <source src="TJ.mp4"  />
    <source src="TJ.ogg" />
</video>
```